# Can I use my own cost function in keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

When compiling a model, you pass a parameter loss into the compile function. For instance:

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
But I was curious if there is a way in Keras to pass in my own cost function?

Comment: I found the following to be quite informative:  https://towardsdatascience.com/advanced-keras-constructing-complex-custom-losses-and-metrics-c07ca130a618  It doesn't add anything to @konstantinosKokos answer so I'm posting as a comment only.  But still may be worth your read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can. A custom loss can be implemented as a function that would take two tensors, i.e. the predicted y and the ground truth, and returns a scalar. The math employed by the function need to be defined over tensorflow functions for the model to be able to backpropagate values through them. If you need your function to accept more input than just y_pred and y_true, you can wrap your custom loss in a broader function, which takes the extra arguments and returns a function that just needs y_true and y_pred. Two examples follow.

#### Mixed loss between binary crossentropy and mse

```python
from keras.losses import mean_squared_error, binary_crossentropy

def my_custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    mse = mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
    crossentropy = binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    return mse + crossentropy
```

#### Weighted mixture (wrapped)

```python
def my_custom_loss_wrapper(mse_weight, xentropy_weight):
   def my_custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
       mse = mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
       crossentropy = binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
       return mse_weight * mse + xentropy_weight * crossentropy
   return my_custom_loss
```

Comment: After defining my custom loss function, do I run the code as follows? :
model.compile(loss='my_custom_loss', optimizer='adam')

Comment: Nope. When the argument to loss is a string, it is mapped against a dictionary of predefined losses with their default arguments. When you want to use custom losses or default losses with non-default arguments, you have to call the pass the function itself, i.e. loss=my_custom_loss` or `loss=my_custom_wrapper(args)` or `loss=adam(lr=0.005)`.